# Android SQLite foreign key help needed?

Tags: android, sqlite

// HANDLER

```
private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE = "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + KEY_CONTENT1 + " text not null);";

private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE2 = "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE2 + " (" + KEY_ID2 + " integer foreign key autoincrement, " + KEY_CONTENT2 + " text not null, " + KEY_CONTENT3 + " text not null);";
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

// ERROR LOG

> ```
> > 09-29 11:54:40.052: INFO/Database(484): sqlite returned: error
> ```
>
> code =
>
> > 1, msg = near "foreign": syntax error 09-29 11:54:40.052:
> >     ERROR/Database(484): Failure 1 (near "foreign": syntax error) on
> >     0x217ba8 when preparing 'create table MY_TABLE2 (_id2 integer
> >     foreign
> >     key autoincrement, Content2 text not null, Content3 text not
> >     null);'.
> >     09-29 11:54:40.062: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(484): Shutting down VM
> >     09-29
> >     11:54:40.062: WARN/dalvikvm(484): threadid=1: thread exiting
> >     with
> >     uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800) 09-29 11:54:40.082:
> >     ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-29
> >     11:54:40.082:
> >     ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
> >     start
> >     activity ComponentInfo{sep.com/sep.com.SepActivity}:
> >     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "foreign": syntax
> >     error:
> >     create table MY_TABLE2 (_id2 integer foreign key autoincrement,
> >     Content2 text not null, Content3 text not null); 09-29
> >     11:54:40.082:
> >     ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >
> > android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
> >     09-29 11:54:40.082: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >
> > android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
> >     09-29 11:54:40.082: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
> >     09-29
> >     11:54:40.082: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >
> > android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
> >     09-29 11:54:40.082: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-29
> >     11:54:40.082: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 09-29 11:54:40.082:
> >     ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 09-29
> >     11:54:40.082: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-29
> >     11:54:40.082: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 09-29
> >     11:54:40.082:
> >     ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >
> > com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> >     09-29 11:54:40.082: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> >     09-29
> >     11:54:40.082: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-29
> >     11:54:40.082:
> >     ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484): Caused by:
> >     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "foreign": syntax
> >     error:
> >     create table MY_TABLE2 (_id2 integer foreign key autoincrement,
> >     Content2 text not null, Content3 text not null); 09-29
> >     11:54:40.082:
> >     ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native
> >     Method)
> >     09-29 11:54:40.082: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >
> > android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1727)
> >     09-29 11:54:40.082: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >     sep.com.handle$SQLiteHelper.onCreate(handle.java:104) 09-29
> >     11:54:40.082: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >
> > android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
> >     09-29 11:54:40.082: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >     sep.com.handle.openToWrite(handle.java:44) 09-29 11:54:40.082:
> >     ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >     sep.com.SepActivity.onCreate(SepActivity.java:38) 09-29
> >     11:54:40.082:
> >     ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >
> > android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> >     09-29 11:54:40.082: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     at
> >
> > android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
> >     09-29 11:54:40.082: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(484):     ... 11 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Creating tables
private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE = "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + KEY_CONTENT1 + " text not null);";

private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE2 = "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE2 + " (" + KEY_ID2 + " integer autoincrement, " + KEY_CONTENT2 + " text not null, " + KEY_CONTENT3 + " text not null, FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_ID2+") REFERENCES "+PARENT_TABLE+" ("+PARENT_TABLE_PRIMARY+"));";
```

Foreign key has references

Comment: 09-29 13:38:37.121: ERROR/Database(276): Failure 1 (near "autoincrement": syntax error) on 0x218e00 when preparing 'create table MY_TABLE2 (_id integer autoincrement, Content2 text not null, Content3 text not null,+  FOREIGN KEY (_id) REFERENCES MY_TABLE (_id));'.


**this error comes when i change the code.**

Answer (score 0):

try this ... 
            String CREATE_MATCH = "CREATE TABLE if not exists "+ TABLE_MATCH 
                    + "(" 
                        + MatchID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," 
                        + MatchTeamA + " INTEGER REFERENCES "+TABLE_TEAM+","
                        + MatchTeamB + " INTEGER REFERENCES "+TABLE_TEAM+")";